# How to silence Android/iOS notifications during app use?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, notifications, mobile-development

I am currently developing an app for visually impaired users and it have been requested that we reduce the amount of alerts from the OS's notification centres that appear during its use.

Is this even possible? I ask as I believe all apps are sandboxed these days to prevent you playing with core OS systems. I have done some Googling and found plenty about registering to the Apple Push Notification service and being able to handle your own messages, but nothing about silencing them all temporarily.

The only possible advice I have is Do Not Disturb, but that's a terrible idea!

Any ideas?

Thanks